# CSS Transition height and padding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a ReactJS fixed-height child component that I want to animate into and out-of existence using `transition: height`.

```
.slider-enter {
    height: 0;
}

.slider-enter.slider-enter-active {
    height: 3pc;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
}

.slider-leave {
    height: 3pc;
}

.slider-leave.slider-leave-active {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
}
```

This works well, however the component in question also has a `border-top` and some `padding-top`.  This is not included in the height transition, so the transition isn't smooth.

Eg: on "enter", the border and padding immediately become visible, then the rest of the component reveals as expected.

[Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/dufilajupo/1/edit?css,js,output)

### My question:

How do you include the height of the padding and border in a `transition: height` rule, or are there any other approaches that eliminate this issue?

### Copy of source for any post-jsbin world:

React Component:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
      return {
          open: false
      };
  },
  render: function () {
    var stuffs = this.state.open ? <div className="sub" /> : null;

    return (
      <div className="box">
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Click Me</button>
        <span>{'Open: ' + this.state.open}</span>
        <CssTransitionGroup transitionName="slider">
          {stuffs}
        </CssTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  },
  toggle: function () {
      this.setState({
          open: !this.state.open
      })
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  clip: rect(10px 20px 20px 0px);
}

.sub {
  height: 3pc;
  background-color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.slider-enter {
    height: 0;
}

.slider-enter.slider-enter-active {
    height: 3pc;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
}

.slider-leave {
    height: 3pc;
}

.slider-leave.slider-leave-active {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Transition the border and padding so that they all collapse together.
- Wrap the target div in a new container, and animate the height of that. You'll need `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Hmm.. I assumed that transitioning the height, border and padding all together would cause 3px shrinkage per "tick" until the border was gone, then 2px shrinkage per tick until the padding was gone, then 1px shrinkage per tick until the height was all gone.... is this not the case?

Comment: Wrapping the content in another `div` did the trick - thanks.